# PayPal's Payflow Gateway SDK Example not working

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal

I downloaded the [.NET SDK](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/Payflow_dotNET_v4.50RC.zip) for Payflow Gateway and followed [these instructions](https://www.x.com/node/2749) on setting up my Payflow Gateway test account, then modified two lines of DOSecureTokenAuth.cs, the User and Connection variables:

```
        UserInfo User = new UserInfo("myacctname", "myacctname", 
                                     "PayPal", "passwd");
        PayflowConnectionData Connection = new PayflowConnectionData(
                                     "pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com", 443);
```

When I run DOSecureTokenAuth.cs a commandline window opens saying:

```
------------------------------------------------------
Executing Sample from File: DOSecureTokenAuth.cs
------------------------------------------------------
RESULT = 0
RESPMSG = Approved
SECURETOKEN = 3BZVLoht6cESPxMkScSau4g4l
SECURETOKENID = 9e09209a562b43739dd5d1a44a3e2d73
DUPLICATE =
Transaction was successful.

The next step would be to redirect to PayPal to display the hosted
checkout page to allow your customer to select and enter payment.

This is only a simple example, which does not take into account things like
RETURN or SILENT POST URL, etc.

Press <Enter> to redirect to PayPal.

Transaction Successful.
Press Enter to Exit ...
```

Clearly successful. Yay. However, the next step, directing the user to PayPal's Hosted Checkout Page always fails with the following error:

```
Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the fields below and try again.
Error: An error has occurred. Please contact the system administrator.
```

The Payflow Gateway docs say I should submit my SECURETOKENID and SECURETOKEN to http://payflowlink.paypal.com (even if you're wanting to use Payflow PRO???), and here's an example of me trying (below is a GET but POST fails the same way):

https://payflowlink.paypal.com/?securetoken=3BZVLoht6cESPxMkScSau4g4l&securetokenid=9e09209a562b43739dd5d1a44a3e2d73&MODE=test&USER1=testuser1&ACCT=5105105105105100&EXPDATE=1212&CVV2=123

I even made a cute little HTML form page based on the PHP example linked above:

```
<form method='post' action='https://payflowlink.paypal.com/'>
<input type='text' name='SECURETOKEN' value='3BZVLoht6cESPxMkScSau4g4l' />
<input type='text' name='SECURETOKENID' value='9e09209a562b43739dd5d1a44a3e2d73' />
<input type='hidden' name='MODE' value='test' />
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

And as expected it died with the same vague error, which implies I have configured my account in some incorrect way. I haven't put in real financial information, because this account is just a developer test account not intended to be used on a live site, but if I read the docs right, this is the expected way to do it.

Since I assume it's configuration, my account is configured with the following settings:

```
PayPal Express Checkout = Enabled
PayPal Email Address and PayPal Sandbox Email Address are configured and going to the same address
Show Confirmation Page = On a PayPal hosted page
Use Silent Post = No
Send email = Yes
AVS Check = No
CVC Check = No
Enable Secure Token = Yes
```

Help! What's causing the vague error?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the example cs file sends the initial secure token request as "Silent" and by default "Silent" mode isn't enabled. Commenting out that line (or enabling Silent mode) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having been through a similar ordeal a couple of years ago, I recommend you try asking for help at the [Paypal Developer Network](https://www.x.com/developers/x.commerce/forums).

When I was developing against their test API I had not success. It turned out that the test URI that I was hitting was an old, outdated version which was still listed in the current documentation that I was working from.

The only way to get information about that was from the people who actually support the test payment gateway. Those people frequent the Paypal Developer forums to which I've linked.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is the Sandbox account you've configured an actual working **Sandbox** account?
If it's not that, it may be another account setting. Contact PayPal Support via https://www.papyal.com/mts and they should be able to sort it out for you.

Comment: Just so nobody else gets confused, the "Sandbox" is only for PayPal testing, which is distinct from Payflow testing. Payflow testing you have to use the live site (manager.paypal.com) and in order to create a "test" account, you cancel out of the signup process once it gets to the financial information. Brilliant design!